# How to use filter to replace elemMatch in aggregation

Tags: mongoose, filter, aggregate

I have a find query in mongoose, but for need i want now to use aggregation,
after search i find that elemMatch didn't work with aggregation and i must use filter,
is there a solution to replace in my query with filter

I use regex on my query :

**my query**

```
 mymodel.find({u_info: {$elemMatch: {ai_id: 1234, response:{ $regex: new RegExp("^myString" , "i") }}}}
```

**Model**

```
var InfosSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

   u_info:[
                {
                    ai_id:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'wt_ai_infos'},
                    question:String,
                    response:String
                }]},

  return conn.model('wt_infos', InfosSchema);
};
```

**my collection**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5aca2ac25c1d8adeb4a2dab0"),
    "u_info": [
      {
        "response": "false",
        "question": "question 1",
        "ai_id": 254
      },
      {
        "response": "myString",
        "question": "question 2",
        "ai_id": 1234
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: can you please post your sample collection

Comment: I already edited